# how to find coordinate of a point on the triangle chord?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have a Right triangle with points `( a=(0,-2), b=(-5,-2), c=(-5,5) )`. its chord length is `d=8.6`. I need to find coordinates of a point on chord `(for example p=d/4.3=2)` as a tuple of (x,y). is there a simple formula to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using trig the equation of the hypotenuse is $y=(5-x)\tan \frac75-2.$ I leave it to you to show why this is right.

Comment: can you tell a main formula? or send a refference? and next, how to extract x and y from this as number? =/

Comment: To use this formula you pick wahtever x value you want, as long as it is a number in the interval $[-5,0].$ Then you substitute your chosen $x$ into the formula in the answer here, and calculate the y value. What results is a point (x,y) which is on the hypotenuse of the right triangle you defined in the question. I myself had not heard of the word chord" used for the hypotenuse, but only guessed that is what you wanted. If it is not, you need to say in your question what is meant by the chord. My process here will produce all the chords, [continued]

Comment: but if you want it to have length 8.6 there are two possibilities, depending on whether it starts at (-5,5) and extends down the hypotenuse, or it starts at (0,-2) and extends up the hypotenuse. You'll need to use the distance formula and solve an equation to finish, I won't do that for you.